# OpenAI Universe getting started example hangs on download

Tags: python, anaconda, openai-gym

I'm trying to run the getting started code at https://github.com/openai/universe#run-your-first-agent and the program hangs on downloading the game content.

[image: printout]

```
import Universe
```

runs correctly and the internet connection is working fine. Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: I also opened an issue on the github repo: https://github.com/openai/universe/issues/32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by jeremyschlatter on the [github repo issue](https://github.com/openai/universe/issues/32):

Manually pulling the docker image by running

`docker pull quay.io/openai/universe.flashgames:0.20.2`

before executing the example code allows the content that was causing problems to be downloaded.

The remaining content can then be downloaded by executing the example code with `python run.py` and the program will run.